# What happens to messages sent over MSMQ and WCF that exceed the receivers quota?

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, readerquotas

If I use `WCF` to send a message over e.g. `Http`, and the message is too large for the recipient, I get a fault at the sender, and can take action.

If I use `WCF` to send a message over `MSMQ` (non-transactional) and the message is too large for the recipient, it seems to disappear and I get no indication either client or server side.

Is there some way I can observe (and take action for) such occurrences?

Comment: What do you mean `too large for the recipient`? Are you talking about messages greater than 4mb?

Comment: @gleng: Messages that exceed the ReaderQuotas configured on the server side.

Comment: Have you checked if the message has been moved to a subqueue? The message might have been treated as a poison message.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your target is an MSMQ, (irrespective to WCF), here are few items to consider.

1. The maximum size of a single message to publish to MSMQ is 4Mb.
2. If a message over 4Mb is tried to be published to MSMQ, you WILL receive the following error:
   [System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Internal Error : Insufficient resources to perform operation.
3. If your requirement is to publish messages over 4Mb to MSMQ, then there are few solutions for this, like,

   - Using NServiceBus
   - Compressing message during publish and Decompressing the same in the retrieval.
   - Implementing the NServiceBus logic, which is, to write the message to a file at a shared location and store the file location in the message.